# unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath' in my android studio 3.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I have recently installed android studio and while creating first project it is showing some unresolved dependencies i have tried updating android studio and tried all suggested answers from stack overflow but none of them worked for me.

Error messasge

[image]

Build.gradle file

[image: build.gradle file]

I am using LAN connection for internet connectivity so is it because of proxy settings ? Though i have tried to set a proxy connection using my LAN proxy address.

Comment: replace your 28.0.0 to 27.1.1 try it.

Comment: still showing the same error @ViralPatel

Comment: check your network

Comment: @krupaChaudhari please add your gradle file

Comment: what is your gradle version?

Comment: Do you check offline wok is checked or not? If yes, then unchecked and build again.

Comment: which gradle ? project or module? @Basi

Comment: I am using gradle 4.6 and plugin version 3.2.1 and i have tried checking and unchecking offline work several times @ViralPatel

Comment: @krupaChaudhari project  gradle

Comment: I have updated my gradle file in my question @Basi

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After adding `mavenCentral()` and `mavenLocal()` in `build.gradle` it worked .

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven{ url 'https://maven.google.com'}
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()

    }
}
```